# Unable to verify deployed contract! Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, bytecode, contract-verification

I already searched and many of the people got this issue, I tried that but unable to fix this issue.

I have deployed a contract and [Contract Address](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x899cf1675eb1a8ca08e0595399547efe128a620f) is here.

I am getting this error
**Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI**
[image]

Contract Verify Option selected.
[image]

Warnings in remix
[image]

I would like to ask why this error comes up? Is this due to warnings or due something else? How can I fix it?

Comment: tried the version 2  as suggested in the page? https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract2?a=0x899cf1675eb1a8ca08e0595399547efe128a620f

Comment: I did it with 0.4.19 and that verified successfully. not working with .21

Comment: With another deployment.

Comment: try using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sol-verifier

Comment: I got the same error and made a post (linked below), but nobody has answered me. Could someone here offer help? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83843/compiler-unable-to-generate-contract-bytecode-and-abi-when-i-try-to-verify-pub